# Парсинг XML > 3 GB

Tags: java, xml

Всем привет, необходимо поменять некоторые параметры в XML файле, со сложной структурой. Ранее данную задачу решал через DocumentFactoryBuilder, как оказалось он работает только на небольших файлах. Каким инструментом можно воспользоваться для решения данной задачи?
Ограничение Java 7.

Comment: Для изменения больших и сложных XML-документов скорее всего поможет XSLT и классы из пакета `javax.xml.transform.*`

Comment: @AlexChermenin - XSLT версий 1.0 и 2.0 полностью загружает весь XML в память. То есть 3 GB не получится обрабатывать. XSLT 3.0 может делать потоковую обработку, однако не знаю, есть ли бесплатные процессоры.

Comment: Нужно использовать потоковый (streaming) API. Ищите по терминам SAX и StAX.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html